# My big numbers formatting function is behaving oddy

Tags: php

```
 function intfix($value) {
        $value = trim($value);
        $value = preg_replace("/[^0-9](.*)$/", '', $value);
        return $value+0;
    }
```

This function is supposed to handle very large numbers and get rid of anything that isn't a number or return 0.

```
echo intfix(123123123123123); // 1
```

The crazy thing is it only return 1 on my live server, but the correct amount on my local server. What's going on here?

Comment: probably you are using a 32 bit operating system and you exceed the integer max value. Need to switch to 64 bit to handle such big numbers. (Well if that's not the fix at least is a smart thing to keep in mind and don't bang your head against the wall when it hits you)

Comment: the error resides in your local server. The live server is correct. how odd is that?

Comment: note by casting to an integer you are only going to be able to represent numbers up to PHP_INT_MAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^0-9](.*)/", '', $value);
```

To:

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", '', $value);
```

What went wrong? You selected 1 number, and than anything what's on the path. By nothing, so you keep the 1 number, because it does not match anything else than a number, and then replace everything by nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You are only selecting the first number in your regex.

Change it:
`preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", '', $value);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = preg_replace("/^[^0-9]+$/", '', $value);
```